# Django server running on a GCE instance cannot connect to postgres cloud SQL

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` that has `django` and an `nginx` as a reverse proxy

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:

  app:
    restart: always
    command: ./startup.sh
    image: region-docker.pkg.dev/project_id/repo/image:tag
    container_name: backend
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/static
    hostname: app

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: region-docker.pkg.dev/project_id/repo/image:tag
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/static
    ports:
      - "80:80" 
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

---

the database connection variables configuration in the `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'Instance': 'project_id:region:instance_name',
        'NAME': 'database_name', 
        'USER': 'username', 
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'database_internal_IP', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

---

whenever I run `docker-compose up` in the VMs CLI the nginx runs perfectly but the django servers comes with this error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
backend  |      Is the server running on host "instance-private-IP" and accepting
backend  |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Note:** when I run `psql -h instance-private-IP -U username` the connection is successfully established

**Note:** when I run the exact same container on my local pc with the same configurations with only the public IP instead of the private IP the container runs just fine

**Note:** the service account attached to the VM has access to the cloud SQL enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple tries of reconfiguring everything (docker-compose, Django, VM configuration)

Nothing worked. Suspiciously what worked for me was restarting the VM instance.